# Update column from another MYSQL table excluding already existing data

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, inner-join, sql-insert

I have 2 tables as described below...

```
table_1
| id | system_id |
| 1  | 3         |
| 2  | 12        |
| 3  | 45        |
| 4  | 7         |

table_2
| id | system_id |
| 1  | 3         |
| 2  | 12        |
```

I'd like to update table_2 with the remaining rows from table_1, excluding the already existing rows.

I tried the following query...

```
UPDATE table_2
INNER JOIN table_2 ON table_2.system_id = table_1.system_id
SET table_2.system_id = table_1.system_id
```

This updates the table_2 with all rows from table_1. I'm unable to work out how to exclude the existing rows.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Please show us the result that you want.

Comment: The result should show table_1 and table_2 to be exactly the same.

Comment: What is the primary key of the tables?

Comment: id is the primary key for both tables

Comment: You aren't invoking table1 please fix the published code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create new rows in `table_2`, then you need `insert`, not `update`. If you want to update `system_id` on existing rows at the same time, you can use `on duplicate key`.

Assuming that the primary key of each table is `id`, you would do:

```
insert into table_2 (id, system_id)
select id, system_id 
from table_1
on duplicate key update system_id = values(system_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the correction @GMB. This has helped me a lot. In the end I used the following... `INSERT INTO table_2
  (system_id)
SELECT table_1.system_id
  FROM table_1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT system_id
                    FROM table_2
                   WHERE table_2.system_id = table_1.system_id)`